# При запуске 2 окна приложения из 1, в нём перестаёт работать clicked.connect(func) кнопки

Tags: python, qt, gui, pyside6

это просто пример кода:

```
from add_word import Ui_add_word
    class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
            def __init__(self):
                self.add_word_open.clicked.connect(self.add_word_launch) #QPushButton
                ...
            def add_word_launch(self):
                win_add_word = QDialog()
                ui = Ui_add_word()
                ui.setupUi(win_add_word)
                win_add_word.show()
```

UI_add_word:

```
class Ui_add_word(QDialog):
    def setupUi(self, add_word):
        self.add_word_in_file.clicked.connect(self.clicked_on_add_word_btn)
        ...

    def clicked_on_add_word_btn(self):
        self.add_word_in_file.setStyleSheet('color:red')
```

При запуске кода внутри Ui_add_word коннект работает, но при запуске из другого файла коннект перестаёт работать, это как то связанно с Event Loop?

Comment: PeFoo, ваш вопрос как и ваш ответ - не понятны. Вам надо предоставить минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и только тогда вы видимо сможите получить некоторые совет.

Comment: @S.Nick, Извиняюсь, порой со мной такое случается что уже уставший сажусь писать код и не понимаю очевидных ошибок, трачу минимальное количество времени на её решение и пишу сюда. Извиняюсь ещё раз)

Answer (score 0):

Аахха, надо было просто добавить в файле MyWindow, где я вызываю 2 окно, win_add_word.exec()